# JMeter discributed testing create counter unique in each slave

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to create a counter which is unique in each slave when using JMeter distributed testing mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "different" counter values on each remote host you can take the following steps:

1. On each remote slave define `offset` property and make it different.

   - on 1st slave add the next line to *user.properties* file:

     ```
     offset=0
     ```
   - on 2nd slave configure this "offset" to be i.e. 10000

     ```
     offset=10000
     ```
   - on 3rd slave - 20000

     ```
     offset=20000
     ```
   - etc.
2. In your Test Plan in [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element refer this "offset" value using [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in "Start" input field like `${__P(offset,)}`

   [image: JMeter Counter Offset]

This way counters will start from 0 on 1st slave, from 10000 on 2nd slave, from 20000 on 3rd slave, etc.

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article to learn more about using counter config element and function in JMeter tests.

Comment: Please can you also specify how to define that offset property in slave??

Comment: The answer contains the instructions already, the property is defined in *user.properties* file of each slave machine. See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) and [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) articles for more details.