# JMeter distributed testing create counter unique in each slave using terraform

Tags: jmeter, terraform

Is there a way to create a counter which is unique in each slave from terraform when using JMeter distributed testing mode?

I got the load testing script from here https://github.com/marcosborges/terraform-aws-loadtest-distribuited. But my requirement is to assign an offset for the slave counter since we would need more than 10M unique.

The solution reference is somewhat related to this -> [JMeter discributed testing create counter unique in each slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636398/jmeter-discributed-testing-create-counter-unique-in-each-slave/41636993?newreg=1b9f11e5b9c1488aaad5f6db43d6f39c)

But it would be a hassle to individually assign offset to more than 50 slaves.

Answer (score 0):

If solution described does not suit you, I don't think there is a way to do that in JMeter.

You'll have to use a 3rd party like Redis for example:

- https://redis.io/commands/incrby/

And use JSR223 + Groovy to handle the incrby call

Comment: what if we try using a random generator in terraform to assign offsets to nodes? but need reference for this

Comment: is there anything in terraform to assign offset in jmeter slaves